# In IE 11 contentWindow.document.execCommand print empty page when Iframe src is pdf. If its image print the content fine

Tags: javascript

var printdoc = document.getElementById('printPDF'); printdoc.contentWindow.document.execCommand('print', false, null);

The above iframe source is Image it is working fine. I am able to print the document in IE 11.

But the source file is PDF. It print the empty page with some header and footer content.. Please help on this issue.